# Parallax effect don't work on smartphone

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, parallax

I want to implement a pure CSS parallax effect in my ionic enviroment. When I start it in the chrome web browser, all working as designed. 
But when I take It on my phone the parallax effect don't work.
Any suggestions?

```
.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.parallax__layer--back {
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}

.parallax__layer--base {
  margin-top: 100vh;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Is it possibly that the tag 'perspective' don't work in ionic?

A test projekt can you see here http://codepen.io/loose11/pen/rVJxVg

Or is it maybe ion-refresh?

**//edit**

If I debug it with chrome://inspect an select (on my smartphone the div is going to transparent blue) the whole ion-scroll, it works...

Comment: What smartphone are you testing this on? If it's not a newer Android phone, it's possible that the webview rendering isn't using the same engine as Chrome.

Comment: I also have crosswalk installed. At this time I'm using a HTC ONE M7 with cynagenmod on it.

Comment: At this time I'm using a HTC One M7 with cynagenmod on it. Further more I have installed the crosswalk plugin.

Comment: Does it work with Crosswalk? I've used Crosswalk and it does wonders for compatibility with older phones.